# iOS - count swipes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to count when the there is a left swipe action. However, with the code I have so far the result is always 1.

Any Ideas Why?

```
- (void)handleSwipes:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    int countLeft = 0;

    if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {

        countLeft += 1;
        imagesequence = @"2.png";
        [_MainBackground setImage:[ UIImage imageNamed: imagesequence]];

         NSLog(@"LEFT = %d", countLeft);
    }


    if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"RIGHT");
        imagesequence = @"3.png";
        [_MainBackground setImage:[ UIImage imageNamed: imagesequence]];
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful for you to show the code where you set up a GestureRecognize and its delegate, so we can see how you have defined your gestured recognizers. Also it would be helpful to show us how/where you defined countLeft...is this with an @synthesize statement or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `int countLeft = 0;` is defined inside the method scope so every time it runs, `countLeft` is defined and initialized to `0`, you'll need to promote that to a wider scope to keep the latest execution value (move definition outside method).

Comment: Thank you so much.. Just moved int outside the void.. works great